# Mouse Cursor on External Monitor

Tags: external-display, cursor

I'm having a strange issue with Windows 10. I have a Laptop with two external monitors. Out of the blue my cursor starting showing only the "working in the background" (white arrow with blue ring next to it).

On the two external monitors (Dell u2415, Dell P2217) it always shows this "working in the background" pointer, even when hovering over links, going into text fields, etc. It's a static cursor.

On my laptop screen, the cursor is working as normal, ie, shows the pointer, changes to the hand when hovering on a link, etc.

I've done a reboot, hard reboot, updated dell display manager, updated intel graphics driver.

Any ideas?

Comment: I get this sometimes... I seems to happen for a day and then stop. I've also discovered that when I screen-share on a video call, other people can see the cursor change icon (and therefore can't understand why I'm struggling with an action like resizing an object).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but cursor was stuck as the arrow. [Cursor in windows 10 shows one icon on external monitors and correct on laptop display](https://superuser.com/questions/1580524/cursor-in-windows-10-shows-one-icon-on-external-monitors-and-correct-on-laptop-d)

My solution was uninstalling *and* deleting the driver for the docking. Just uninstalling did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Also managed to solve this for a customer today by removing DisplayLink Graphics (software installed by/for a Laptop Dock). Dock still functions perfectly with the display connected from it and USB devices, but it no longer causes the issue on the secondary monitors.